# Php create dateformat from string

Tags: php, datetime

I have following date string `16012010`. This string is writeen in `dmY` format. I want to create it `Y-m-d`. `strtotime()` function didn't working . It creates `1970-01-01 00:00::00`

Comment: It would seem the answer is the top result when you search for your title in Google...

Comment: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', '16012010');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and provide format as a first argument:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', '16012010');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');  // outputs `2010-01-16`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`date_create_from_format`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse a date from a certain format to a datetime object.

```
$datetime = date_create_from_format('dmY', '16012010');
```